# question about incompatible printf format specifiers

Tags: c, c99

I was just looking through the man page for printf and something occurred to me. I was wondering if there are any "language lawyers" here which could answer a relatively simple question :-P.

So the 't' modifier is defined as

> A following integer conversion
>   corresponds to a ptrdiff_t argument.

So what is **supposed** to happen if you combine this with an unsigned integer conversion? Clearly o,u,x and X all all intended to be interpreted as unsigned values, while d and i are signed.

Likewise, there are signed/unsigned versions for all modifiers (int/unsigned int, `size_t`/ `ssize_t`, etc) except `ptrdiff_t`.

In practice, nothing bad happens since unsigned versions of types occupy the same amount of space as the signed versions. So the right about of bytes get popped off the stack.

So nothing "bad" happens, in fact, in prints the expected value for all things tested except the "`INT_MIN`" (assuming that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(ptrdiff_t)`.

```
printf("%tu %td\n", INT_MIN, INT_MIN);
```

prints

```
2147483648 -2147483648
```

on a 32-bit system.

Does the standard have any opinion about this? I figure the answer will be "undefined behavior." But I figured I'd ask ;).

Comment: Does this have anything to do with C++ (at least before C++0x)?  Is printf() etc. going to be changed in C++0x to conform with C99?  I think you should remove the C++ tag.

Comment: ptrdiff_t is defined in cstddef in c++. printf obviously exists in c++ as well. I am not aware of c++0x changing printf at all.

Comment: hrmm, seems that c++ may not have the c99 't' modifier. Fair enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing to see here. The code you've written is legal.

Just some facts as to why:

- all signed integer types have unsigned counterparts, with the same size/alignment requirements
- `ptrdiff_t` is prescribed to be a signed integer type by the standard. Therefore, it has an unsigned twin. (In fact, similar logic applies to `size_t` as well - `ssize_t` is not C, but POSIX)
- the `t` length specifier must work with `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, `X` types

Comment: what is the valid unsigned equivalent to ptrdiff_t?

Comment: It has no special name - you can only say that if ptrdiff_t is "long long" then its unsigned counterpart is "unsigned long long" etc.

Comment: The important fact you omitted is that, in cases where the value fits in both the signed and unsigned variants of an integer type, it has the same representation, and the standard explicitly allows passing the "wrong" argument type in this case (which is only possible for functions without prototypes and variadic functions, anyway). As far as I can tell, it would be UB to pass a negative `ptrdiff_t` value when the format specifier expects an unsigned type.